# CodeIgniter method Cannot get File Path Correctly

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, url, base-url

I parsed a html into Header, Sidebar, Content, Footer etc.. And main view put together.. It is working when I calling view from mycontroller/index but it isnt working when I calling view from mycontroller/method.. Pseude Code below;

Controller;

```
class welcome extends CI_Controller{
   public function index(){
      $data['content'] = "**main**_page";
      $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
   }

   public function deneme(){
      $data['content'] = "**another**_page";
      $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
   }
}
```

View;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <?php $this -> load -> view("includes/head_view");?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php $this -> load -> view("includes/navbar_view");?>
    <?php $this -> load -> view($content);?>
    <?php $this -> load -> view("includes/footer_view"); ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Example Sub View

```
<img src="<?php base_url(); ?>assets/img/image1.jpg">
```

When I open below address, everything working fine, images loading

http://localhost/myproject

But When open below, images is not loading

http://localhost/myproject/welcome/deneme

I check the images url from Google Chrome> Page Source Code..
The link writing like that;
localhost/myproject/welcome/assets/img/image1.jpg

instead of

localhost/myproject/assets/img/image1.jpg

It's adding controller name to all links how can resolve it
Thank you

Comment: what is your `base_url` in config?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you define your `base_url` it says "URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash":

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';
```

Comment: Still same.. This is adding "welcome" string to paths.. 
http://localhost/myproject/welcome/assets/img/image1.jpg

Comment: That isn't the default behavior. Is your localhost actually like `localhost:8080` or something?

Comment: I checked, not :(

Comment: try: `<?php echo base_url("/assets/img/image1.jpg"); ?>`

Comment: I tried, Now Images not shown for both url
localhost/myproject/welcome
localhost/myproject/welcome/deneme
In the source code: <img src="">
It seems I have problem with url

Comment: you need to `echo` and make sure `url_helper` is loaded